# Disable maximize button and resizing window in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, window

I have modality window. I want the window to be able to be minimized and closed, but not resized or maximized.

How do I disable the maximize button and prevent resizing of the window?

Answer (score 45):

You can do it with `stage.setResizable(false);` You can also remove window buttons with `stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);`

EDIT: You can always use HBox to create custom buttons, after window decoration is removed. Anyway providing your code can help :)

Answer (score 22):

This is the best way

```
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```

example:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/homePage.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Resizing");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 750, 601));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
primaryStage.maximizedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue)
                primaryStage.setMaximized(false);
        });
```

It listens for the maximize event then checks whether it's actually maximizing through `if (newVale)` then forces the stage to disable maximization.

Answer (score 1):

```
stage.setMaxHeight(double TheHeightYouGot);
stage.setMaxWidth(double TheWidthYouGot);
stage.setResizable(false);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do this :

```
primaryStage.setResizable(false);
```